# How to write XML elements with namespaces in python

Tags: python, xml

I just tried this python 2.5 snippet to write some XML:

```
xmldoc = xml.dom.minidom.Document()
feed = xmldoc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", "feed")
xmldoc.appendChild(feed)
print xmldoc.toprettyxml()
```

I expected the output to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" />
```

Instead I got this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<feed />
```

Apparently the XML namespace is silently being ignored here. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

minidom [does not support](http://bugs.python.org/issue1621421) namespace normalization. The only workaround I'm aware of is explicitely setting the xmlns attribute with

```
xmldoc.documentElement.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom')
```